# How to keep updating with php after loading page

Tags: javascript, php, ping

I want my page to ping, over the course of a few seconds, a PC to check when it has finished booting. I'd also like for the page to give some more or less live feedback to the user in the form of:

```
Pinging... Host unreachable
Pinging... Host unreachable
Pinging... PC is on!
```

Kind of what pinging looks in the shell. Since php is server side (which I always interpreted as all php stuff needs to be done before shipping the page to the user) I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. I suspect some client side script could do the trick, but I've never used any nor do I have any idea how to make, say, javascript, interact with php. I have basic knowledge of php and java, not javascritp though.

Thanks in advance, any input is appreciated

Comment: It's very simple, just google for some AJAX tutorials

Comment: any tips as to what precisely should I be looking for in Ajax? Part of the difficulty I've had so far is the very wording of the problem, I'm not even sure how to google for it

Comment: To be honest, the very first result after typing in "ajax tutorial" should give you a good start: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ just replace the "ajax_info.txt" with your PHP script, and probably add to the div rather than replacing the contents. Have a go and make a new question for any specific issue you have

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with PHP. PHP runs synchronously and serves a static web page.

EDIT:

To be clear, PHP does not interact with javascript. PHP just serves pages. So PHP might serve you a page that you request using AJAX, but PHP would not be directly involved. Your AJAX request would be communicating with the server, not with the PHP runtime.

Comment: Probably because he already said he understands that he needs to use a client-side language.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a *server-side* scripting language, meaning that all processes are handled by the server before being sent to the client.

Since you wish to monitor the page after it's been loaded, you need to use a *client-side* scripting language, such as Javascript or Flash. Note, however, that the client may not have the ability to execute Javascript/Flash programs.

Still, if you're looking to communicate with the page after after it's been served to the client, the best way to do so would be through **Ajax**. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (A Javascript library) has pretty nice Ajax support right out of the box, so I'd recommend looking there first.